# JS:Want to animate on clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to animate/colorify the div on clicking the button 'Animate'
Can you test my code and suggest some changes or add some code ?

My code looks like this:-

```css
.anime {
  animation: coloranimate 5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes coloranimate {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: yellow;
    border: 4px solid black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes coloranimate {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: yellow;
    border: 4px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anime" class="anime">
</div>
<button>Animate</button>
```

I want to animate/colorify the div using the animate button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.addClass()` on click on the button, once you add the class which contains the animation property, the animation will automatically start.

---

**See code snippet:**

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#anime').addClass("anime");
});
```

```css
#anime {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}

.anime {
  animation: coloranimate 5s;
}

@keyframes coloranimate {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: yellow;
    border: 4px solid black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes coloranimate {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: yellow;
    border: 4px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anime">
</div>
<button>Animate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to add jquery for achieve your requirement.

Try this code it may helps you.

**Edit**

it is with plain javascript.

```js
function addAnime() {
var classadd = document.getElementById('anime');
classadd.className = 'anime';
}
```

```css
.anime {
  animation: coloranimate 5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes coloranimate {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: yellow;
    border: 4px solid black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes coloranimate {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: yellow;
    border: 4px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anime" class="">
</div>
<button onclick="addAnime()">Animate</button>
```

Comment: "Here you have to add jquery" You don't **have to**, this can be done with vanilla javascript so jQuery isn't a **must have** or  **have to** use.

Comment: Ok doing it with vanilla javascript

Comment: I'm not saying jQuery shouldn't be used, I'm just saying you shouldn't make `jQuery` appear like a requirement/must have/use to enable someone have an animations like this work when it can be done without the use of a plugin/library

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on click via javascript on the `#anime` element which then has the animation ...

```js
$('.myButton').on('click', function(){
    $('#anime').addClass('animate-now');
});
```

```css
.anime {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes coloranimate {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: yellow;
    border: 4px solid black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes coloranimate {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: yellow;
    border: 4px solid black;
  }
}

.anime.animate-now {
  animation: coloranimate 5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anime" class="anime">
</div>
<button class="myButton">Animate</button>
```